# Laravel 8 URI in request GET is not valid

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8, php-8

I am working on a new project using Laravel 8. I only have 2 routes at the moment. My first on "/" works but my second "/pricelist" returns a 404 and I have been trying everything for the past 2 hours to get it working to no avail. Any help would be appreciated at this point.

wep.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\priceListController;
use App\Http\Controllers\dashboardController;

Route::get('/', [dashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
Route::get('/pricelist', [priceListController::class, 'index'])->name('pricelist');
```

- http://x.x.x.x/operations/phpl/ Works and shows the dashboard
- http://x.x.x.x/operations/phpl/pricelist Gives a 404

Log says:

> ZSRV_MSG0016: URI in request GET /operations/phpl/pricelist HTTP/1.1
> is not valid

[image]

My httpd.conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost /home/operations/phpl:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/operations/phpl/public

    <Directory /home/operations/phpl>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess in /public looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried doing a dump-autoload and also a route:clear but it did not help.

I might be missing something obvious here but I just don't see it ...

The routes seems to be valid caus it appears in the route list. So I think this is a server issue ... Might come from httpd.conf?

$ php artisan route:list

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI       | Name      | Action                                         | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /         | index     | App\Http\Controllers\dashboardController@index | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user  |           | Closure                                        | api        |
|        |          |           |           |                                                | auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | pricelist | pricelist | App\Http\Controllers\priceListController@index | web        |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

My full httpd.conf looks like this

```
LoadModule zend_enabler_module /QSYS.LIB/QHTTPSVR.LIB/QZFAST.SRVPGM

LoadModule ibm_ssl_module /QSYS.LIB/QHTTPSVR.LIB/QZSRVSSL.SRVPGM
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LiveLocalCache Off
SSLCacheEnable
<Location />
<LimitExcept GET HEAD OPTIONS POST TRACE>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny From all
</LimitExcept>
</Location>

Options -ExecCGI -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Includes -IncludesNoExec -Indexes -MultiViews
DefaultType www/unknown
Options +Includes
Listen *:80
MaxKeepAliveRequests 5
TimeOut 120
KeepAliveTimeout 4
LogMaint logs/error_log 10 0
LogLevel Debug
AccessFileName .htaccess
DirectoryIndex welcome.html index.html index.php
CGIConvMode %%EBCDIC/EBCDIC%%
IndexOptions +DescriptionWidth=60 -FancyIndexing -FoldersFirst -IconHeight -IconsAreLinks -IconWidth -IgnoreCase -IgnoreClient +NameWidth=60 +NameMinWidth=15 -ScanHTMLTitles -SelectiveDirAccess -ShowSmallFileBytes -ShowOwner -SuppressColumnSorting -SuppressDescription -SuppressHTMLPreamble -SuppressIcon -SuppressLastModified -SuppressRules -SuppressSize -TrackModified -VersionSort
HeaderName README
<Directory />
Order Allow,Deny
Deny From all
UserID %%SERVER%%
</Directory>

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fastcgi-script .php

<Location /operations/php>
Allow from all
</Location>

<Directory "/home/operations/php">
Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost /home/operations/phpl:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/operations/phpl/public
    AccessFileName .htaccess

    <Directory /home/operations/phpl>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Try remove slash near pricelist

Comment: You ran `php artisan optimize` or `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: I tried route:clear already but that did not work

Comment: I tried removing the / near pricelist and same result. I also tried adding one at the end. But I don't think the problem come from Laravel it self. It's not my first project, but it's my first time building one in this environment. I think it could be something missing in the server or in the httpd.conf